# How can I use functional update with event.currentTarget.value in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, events, setstate

First, please check my code.

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('nick');

const handleChangeName = (e) => {
  setName(prevState => e.currentTarget.value)
}

return (
  <input value={name} onChange={handleChangeName} />
)
```

I'm trying to do functional update not

```js
setName(e.currentTarget.value)
```

However, with this code,

```js
const handleChangeName = (e) => {
  setName(prevState => e.currentTarget.value)
}
```

I am not getting the right value for some reason. If you know what is the problem or the answer, please let me know! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use target instead of currentTarget

```
    const handleChangeName = (e) => {
  setName(prevState =>  e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Khalfoun. But why does e.currentTarget.value is not working?